# load pages dynamically using jQuery $.post in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a home page in which i have two DIVs (left & right).
in left div i will be having some items. and in right div its details.
(please see the image)

[image: Scenario]

here, clicking on an item in the left div, its corresponding details should get loaded.
i have two separate views for the two divs. I am able to load the left view from the controller function.

But I should load the right div based on the `item_id` of the left div item without any page refresh.

for that I will send `item_id` via jQuery `$.post` and get the `details_page`.

my view of the details page is as fillows

```
<div class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
<div class="details">
    <div class="author"><?php echo $author; ?></div>
    <div class="pagedata"><?php echo $pagedata; ?></div>
</div>
```

these PHP variables should get replaced when details page gets loaded.

Please help me in coding the above scenario using jQuery in codeigniter.

Comment: make your life simpler and use **jquery vertical tabs** I don't see any reason why AJAX is needed here. use the proper tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP controller, you need a method that serves the views :

```
class Foo extends CI_Controller {
    public function getItem($item) {
        // the view holds the html for the right div
        $this->load->view($item);
    }   
}
```

in jquery, you can then fetch the view like this:

```
$.get('example.com/foo/getItem/item1', function(resp){
    $('#contentDiv').html(resp);
}, 'html');
```

You would, of course, call this jquery code snippet everytime a pane on the left div is clicked with the appropriate item name.